# How to combine two csv files in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have two different csv sample files:

first.csv

```
name,school
Derrick, schoolA
Peter,schoolB
```

second.csv

```
age  ,address
21,abc
22,sdc
```

I need to combine the two csv files to one. So the result expected is :

combined.csv

```
 name,school,age  ,address
    Derrick,schoolA, 21,abc
    Peter,schoolB, 22,sdc
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using pandas?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide a sample snippet to show where you are stuck at the moment since SO is not a code writing platform. Long story short: It is possible using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) if you make sure that both dataframes are of equal length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('second.csv')

combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

But you need to make sure that `df1` and `df2` have the same amount of rows. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks :) This actually helps. Just one question. How can I generate a csv file from combined_df?